# Need Help Completing a Game

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to create a higher number card game between me and an AI, but it always says the house wins, no matter what I input. If someone could help me figure out why my if, else statement isn't activating, I'd appreciate it.

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Extra Credit -->
<!-- Jordan Smith -->
</head>

<body>
<h1> Beat the House! </h1>


<script>
var num1 = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 10.", "");
var result = Number(num1);
num1 = parseFloat(num1);

{
document.write("</p>" + num1 + " is your number. </p>");
}

for(i=0; i < 1; i++){
var num2 = document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + " ");
}
{
document.write(" is the house's number.");
}

{
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
}


if (num1 > num2) {
document.write("You have the higher number! You win!");
} else {
document.write("The house has the higher number! You lose!");
}


</script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Number("num1")` isn't making a number from the variable `num1`, it is trying to make a number from the literal string `"num1"`

Comment: Alright. I fixed it, for some reason though nothing has changed.

Comment: Because you also seem to think document.write() returns a value when it doesnt

Comment: Oh. Right. What would I do to return the value, then?

Comment: nothing, just like the rest of your `document.write`s

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` doesn't return anything, so it's converted to `NaN` for inequalities. Comparison with `NaN` is always false, so it treats it as the house wins, in this case.

What you probably want is:

```
// num2 is a number
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.write(num2 + " ");
```

Comment: What would I input instead of document.write?

Answer (score 0):

`var num2 = document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + " ");` will not return anything in your case.

The solution to the above is something like that:

```
for(i=0; i < 1; i++){
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
{
document.write(num2+" is the house's number.");
}
```

And for the future, You can always check what the variables are holding, by outputting them to console like that:

```
console.log(num1);
console.log(num2);
```

That way You will know that num1 would output whatever You told it to, and num2 (in Your example) would output NaN - and since You cannot compare a number to NaN: if-else statement will always go to else.